# IOS Framework Localization not working

Tags: ios, localization, ios-frameworks

I have a framework created from our app, and the framework when added to a new project to be used, it works perfectly.

Now we want to add localization for different languages and we did that in the app, and everything works good, but now we want to update our framework to be also localized with multiple languages. So we added all the localized xib and its strings inside the framework, but only English is being shown all the time from the nib files in the framework.

I am not really familiar with frameworks, since it was done by anyother person, and we just follow how to change the files and create updated frameworks.

I have been trying to find some information on the internet, but all i have found is how to change the UILabel inside the code, and not by localizing the nib files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I know this question was asked more than a year ago, but I encountered this issue recently and I would like to share what I did to resolve this.

Your framework's localization is probably working just fine, you just have to make sure that the project using your framework supports localization as well.

Go to your project's Info.plist and look for `CFBundleLocalizations` (add it if it doesn't exist). Add the language codes you want to support and run.

List language codes are available here:
http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

Comment: thanks a lot. I got this problem today. will try your answer.

Comment: In my case I added a localization for the language I was trying to test at the bottom of the "Info" tab within the project settings. That got the application to start using the system defined locale instead of using "en_US" every time.